# UNION and NOT In Together

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT name FROM table1
 WHERE name NOT IN (
    SELECT name, school FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT name, school FROM table3
 )
```

This syntax keeps flagging error near syntax 'Union'. Any suggestion on how to fix this please?

Comment: There's no way this SQL will give you that error. It might however tell you there is a syntax error near the keyword `table` because you have a space before the `3`. Are you sure this is your SQL?

Comment: Also why `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`? And have you considered `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`? See https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: and what are you trying to do with `name NOT IN (SELECT name, school)`? you can't compare one column on the left with two on the right

Comment: You may also get better performance dropping the `UNION` altogether and having two `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clauses.

Comment: yes that is the query without space between table3 and i am getting that error. I am still not sure what I am doing wrong. I even run the sub select statement only to test and it was good but together with the NOT IN, i get that error

Comment: Show the *exact* error and explain where you are getting this error. Is it from Management Studio, your application, a code editor, something else?

Comment: Please show the exact SQL you are using, it looks like you may be trying to give a simplified example, however as has been shown in a couple of attempted answers, the simplified version (sans the fix on multiple columns inside the 'not in') works.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery, only select the `name` column that's used as a filter.  Unless you need combination of the `name` and `school` columns, in which case they'll need to be concatenated.  The space in the name of `table3` will need to be removed, unless this is the actual name of the table.  If it is, it will be to be enclosed in brackets, i.e. `[table 3]`.

```
SELECT name FROM table1
 WHERE name NOT IN (
    SELECT name FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT name FROM table3
 )
```

Comment: Do you still have the space in the name of table3?

Comment: No i do not. I have three tables and I am trying to check for element in table1 that do not appear on either table2 and table3

Comment: Are you still receiving the "error near syntax Union" error?

Comment: How are you submitting the SQL?

Comment: Executing directly on Aqua studio IDE

Answer (score 0):

This is functionally the same and may be faster in some cases

```
SELECT name 
FROM table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.name = t2.name
left join table3 as t3 on t1.name = t3.name
where coalesce(t2.name,t3.name,'new') = 'new'
```

you can also use a where clause like this:

```
where t2.name is null and t3.name is null
```